# Proguard error log giving wrong library/class name

Tags: java, android, ide, proguard, android-proguard

I been trying to generate an APK with `Proguard` and every time I get this error. It warns me about some inner class that I can't find and the name seems to be obfuscated like the following:

> class Error:(b.a.a.a.a.b.o)

here is my proguard file:

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-verbose
-dontpreverify
#-dontshrink
#-dontoptimize
-keepattributes *Annotation*, Exceptions, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile, SourceDir, LineNumberTable, LocalVariableTable, LocalVariableTypeTable, Synthetic, EnclosingMethod, RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations, RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations, AnnotationDefault, InnerClasses

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep class android.content.Context {
    public java.io.File getExternalCacheDir();
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-dontwarn java.awt.**
-keep class java.awt.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.**

# Allow obfuscation of android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**
# to avoid problem on Samsung 4.2.2 devices with appcompat v21
# see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder

-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.*MenuBuilder*, android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

##################
#.___ My project name __.#
##################

-keep public class com.myprojectname.** { public *; }
-dontwarn com.myprojectname.**

##################
#.___ Amplitude __.#
##################

-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class okio.** { *; }

#-dontwarn android.util.FloatMath
-keep class android.util.FloatMath { *; }

##################
#.___ Glide __.#
##################

-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}

##################
#.___ JavaCV __.#
##################

-dontwarn org.bytedeco.javacv.**
-keep class org.bytedeco.javacv.** { *; }

-dontwarn org.bytedeco.javacpp.**
-keep class org.bytedeco.javacpp.** { *; }

-keep @org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation interface * { *; }

-keep @org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.Platform public class *

-keep @interface org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.*,javax.inject.*

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @org.bytedeco.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @org.bytedeco.* <methods>;
}

##################
#.___ Facebook __.#
##################

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }

##################
#.___ Twitter __.#
##################

-keepclassmembers class com.mopub.** { public *; }
-keep public class com.mopub.**
-keep public class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface {}

-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventInterstitial {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventNative {}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info {*;}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

##################
#.___ MP4Parser __.#
##################

-keep class * implements com.coremedia.iso.boxes.Box { *; }

-dontwarn com.coremedia.iso.boxes.**
-keep class com.coremedia.iso.boxes.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.**
-keep class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.ttml.**
-keep class com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.ttml.** { *; }

##################
#.___ Crashlitics __.#
##################

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

And here is the complete error log I'm getting:

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class Error:(b.a.a.a.a.b.o) that doesn't come with an Error:associated
>   EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended Error:solution is to recompile the class from source,
>   using an up-to-date compiler Error:and without specifying any
>   "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring Error:this warning
>   is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class. Error:warning:
>   Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   Error:(b.a.a.a.a.b.n) that doesn't come with an Error:associated
>   EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended Error:solution is to recompile the class from source,
>   using an up-to-date compiler Error:and without specifying any
>   "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring Error:this warning
>   is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class. Error:Uncaught
>   translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable
>   type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type int using a
>   local variable of type
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$e. This is symptomatic
>   of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:
>   local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type
>   float using a local variable of type int. This is symptomatic of
>   .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:
>   local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type
>   float using a local variable of type android.view.MotionEvent. This is
>   symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable
>   information. Error:Uncaught translation error:
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch:
>   attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a
>   local variable of type long. This is symptomatic of .class
>   transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:
>   local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type
>   java.lang.Object using a local variable of type int. This is
>   symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable
>   information. Error:Uncaught translation error:
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch:
>   attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a
>   local variable of type char. This is symptomatic of .class
>   transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:
>   local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type
>   java.lang.Object using a local variable of type int. This is
>   symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable
>   information. Error:Uncaught translation error:
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch:
>   attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a
>   local variable of type int. This is symptomatic of .class
>   transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:
>   local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type
>   int using a local variable of type
>   android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerCompat. This is
>   symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable
>   information. Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':myprojectname:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero
> >     exit value 2 Information:BUILD FAILED

Any hint would be greatly appreciated ^ ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get the correct library names by changing the build variants from release to debug.