# Android - Origin of exception

Tags: android

Can you tell me the origin, which class, where the error comes up in this stackstrace?

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1241)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1305)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1600)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:92)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:131)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder` Is it when you press the overflow button? Ensure you are using the latest version of the support lib and ensure your compile version matches the support version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError for code in an Java library on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android)