# Xamarin Android - Print to the application output in Release mode

Tags: logging, xamarin, xamarin.android

To patch [some crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder) on samsung and wiko devices, I have to run my application on device in Release mode. But I would like to see the output of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` in the application output.

I've enabled developer instrumentation, as well as defined the DEBUG constant in the options ; I can set breakpoints, but the WriteLine outputs still aren't shown in the console.
[image: Debugging options]

[image: other debugging options]

How can I do ?

Comment: FWIW: "I've enabled developer instrumentation, as well as defined the DEBUG constant in the options" - if you make those changes, what you have is, in effect, no longer "Release" mode. The timing is different, and JIT is disabled (because you've attached a debugger). Better to NOT make those changes - you can still use Android Log output to logcat as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `Xamarin.Android` use Android's `Log` utility and watch/filter the `logcat` output for your messages.

#### Example:

```
string TAG = "StackOverflow";
Log.Info(TAG,  $"This is a Info message: {DateTime.Now}");
Log.Debug(TAG, $"This is a debug message");
Log.Warn(TAG,  $"Warning! Warning! Will Robinson Warning! Warning!");
Log.Error(TAG, $"Error, contact support with error code 99 for assistance");
```

#### Logcat Output (via cmd-line or Android Device Monitor):

```
>adb logcat |grep StackOverflow

08-03 11:58:46.282  2338  2338 I StackOverflow: This is a Info message: 8/3/2016 11:58:46 AM
08-03 11:58:46.282  2338  2338 D StackOverflow: This is a debug message
08-03 11:58:46.282  2338  2338 W StackOverflow: Warning! Warning! Will Robinson Warning! Warning!
08-03 11:58:46.282  2338  2338 E StackOverflow: Error, contact support with error code 99 for assistance
```

Comment: Just as he says. Use dependency services to use the native APIs to write your logs, don't use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` for this purpose.  In you Dependency service, you can even check for the `DEBUG` flag to log only if DEBUG flag is on and thus get the same behaviour than `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` (behaviour that you can of course modify when you need it).