# Xamarin App SQL Server Connection not working in release mode

Tags: android, sql-server, xamarin

I have a C# Android app that connect to a SQL Server database. I noticed that if I build in Release mode, the connection to the database is not working. But if I build in Debug mode, it works fine. What could be causing this?

I already set the user permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And this is my settings

[image]

And this is my Sql Server connection

[image]

Comment: See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/124846/xamarin-android-sql-connection-works-in-debug-but-sql-connection-does-not-work-in-release, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82933/sql-connection-working-on-debug-mode-not-on-release and https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3164/release-mode-sql-server-connection-error

Comment: The first 2 I already applied but still now working

But the 3rd i can't apply because i cannot find the **Internationalization section, select the [X] mideast checkbox.**


This is the suggestion on step 3 can you assist me on this. Thank a lot I really appreciate your response


Click Project > Project Name Options
In the left-pane, click Build > Android Build.
In the right-panel, click the Advanced tab.
In the Internationalization section, select the [X] mideast checkbox.
Click OK, then rebuild your app.

Comment: Update your question with the exception thrown and the logcat

Comment: im sorry but how can i get the exception thrown in release mode?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748170/xamarin-android-print-to-the-application-output-in-release-mode

Comment: Thanks for your response it help me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve the issue by setting up the

Linkers properties to
**SDK ASSSEMBLIES ONLY**

and

Additional support encodings to **MIDEAST,WEST**

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).