# Xamarin App SQL Server Connection not working in release mode, encoding 1252

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin app (Visual Studio 2019) that works perfectly in debug mode, but it doesn't in release mode. I cannot connect to SQL-Server and encoding 1252 seems to be missing.

I tried all hints (Linker options, encoding West, connection via IP, connection with/without dapper, etc.) I could find in other questions, but still no success.

Does anyone have another hint, tip, whatsoever? I'm close to setting up a webservice for getting the data...

Comment: You could try the suggestion in the link to set the Linking and Additional support encodings. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65914268/11850033

Comment: Hi Wendy, I already tried those hints. I added references to the encoding dlls (i18N and i18N.West) in my xamarin project and after that it worked.