# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for MainActivity while running the location update sample code

Tags: android

I am following the training tutorial on [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html): . It gives some exceptions at run time, following is the few initial lines of log trace:

```
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.location/com.example.android.location.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.location.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.location-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.location-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.location.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.location-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.location-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
07-07 10:54:51.408: E/AndroidRuntime(31450):    ... 11 more
```

Below is my manifest file code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.location"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:description="@string/app_description"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.location.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.android.location.ReceiveUpdatesIntentService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="false"></service>
</application>
```

i also added the internet permission but it is not working

Comment: check your manifest and add the MainActivity class perfectly..or show your manifest here..

Comment: Please post your manifest file

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898031/1785412

Comment: @RanjitPati i posted my manifest file here...please help me...

Comment: are you sure..that your MainActivity comes under com.example.android.location package..just check the MainActivity class, the package name and also the spelling..if all things are fine then just change the package name(both in class and in manifest)..and let me know..

Comment: @RanjitPati  still getting the same error...and tried in new project and in that also getting the same error

Comment: ok..can you change the MainActivity name to some other name and clean the project..i think it will help you..and also never use `com.example.....` ..always use a valid package name..

Comment: @RanjitPati there is no effect of that also...i am still getting the same error...

Comment: i think you downloaded the zip and import the project..right ?

Comment: @RanjitPati  No, i tried that but not able to import that..then i copied the code from that project files and made neccesary changes. Can you please send me the code for updating the location in background at regular intervals.

Comment: you just google it..there are many conversations and tutorials you can found..you may check this link.. https://scotthelme.co.uk/android-location-services/ ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem starting an `Activity` which extends `MapActivity`.  It took some time and research to find the answer.  Adding `uses-library` in manifest.xml under `application` tag fixed the issue:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```