# Use phonegap features in an existing android application

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am new to Phonegap. I need to use cordova webview in my existing application.

Can someone help me out, if I can use it in my existing android application by adding jar files.

I have checked these in Phonegap/cordova tutorial pages, but it didn't gave me much satisfaction. Also, if someone can provide the steps, it would be much appreciated.

Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this guide

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_webviews_index.md.html#Embedding%20WebViews

and let us know where you have the problem.

You can also follow this blog post from one of the cordova team
https://web.archive.org/web/20140514125044/http://www.infil00p.org/advanced-tutorial-using-cordovawebview-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good resource. Complete step by step guide.

[Embedding a Cordova WebView into an Android fragment](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/app-sample-android-phonegap/wiki/Embed-Webview-in-Android-Fragment)

> This tutorial demonstrates how to embed a Cordova WebView into an
>   Android fragment. The [Phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html) already provides a good
>   overview on how to embed a Cordova WebView in an activity however
>   there are some key differences when using Fragments.

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQXHDIe7bVU](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQXHDIe7bVU)

and check this.

[How to implement phonegap/cordova in android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694522/how-to-implement-phonegap-cordova-in-android-webview)