# NoClassDefFoundError in sliding FragmentActivity

Tags: android

When I try to run my android application , it crashes on `slidingfregmentactivity` class. it gives the error
`noclassdeffoundError`. please help me out

My logcat :

```
09-17 10:33:05.439: W/dalvikvm(573): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingFragmentActivity; (115)
09-17 10:33:05.439: W/dalvikvm(573): Link of class 'Lcom/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingFragmentActivity;' failed
09-17 10:33:05.449: W/dalvikvm(573): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/simson/saibamobi/ResponsiveUIActivity; (515)
09-17 10:33:05.449: W/dalvikvm(573): Link of class 'Lcom/simson/saibamobi/ResponsiveUIActivity;' failed
09-17 10:33:05.449: E/dalvikvm(573): Could not find class 'com.simson.saibamobi.ResponsiveUIActivity', referenced from method com.simson.saibamobi.SplashScreen$1.run
09-17 10:33:05.449: W/dalvikvm(573): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 798 (Lcom/simson/saibamobi/ResponsiveUIActivity;) in Lcom/simson/saibamobi/SplashScreen$1;
09-17 10:33:05.449: D/dalvikvm(573): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0091
09-17 10:33:06.539: I/System.out(573): isreg: false
09-17 10:33:06.539: D/AndroidRuntime(573): Shutting down VM
09-17 10:33:06.549: W/dalvikvm(573): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.simson.saibamobi.ResponsiveUIActivity
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.simson.saibamobi.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:118)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
09-17 10:33:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: line at `SplashScreen.java:118` ?

Comment: Are you using any third party jar library file?If yes then check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898031/1785412

Comment: If you are using 3rd party api then make sure you have added that project in your project's build path. Make sure the java file resides inside `com.simson.saibamobi.ResponsiveUIActivity` package and your project is able to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using third party jar file then right click on project-->click on properties-->java build path-->order and export and check the jar file.
Clean and build the project and run again.

To add Slide Menu you can use this link:

http://techbirds.in/integrating-sliding-menu-navigation-in-android/