# android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError even though the class IS there

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

**Skip to my *EDIT* section below - new project setup and new question there.  I left the original stuff here for context...**

I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError in my Android project - in this case it's complaining that it can't find the the UserVoice plugin I just added:

[image: stack trace]

Triggered by this code:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
...
import com.uservoice.uservoicesdk.Config;
import com.uservoice.uservoicesdk.UserVoice;
...
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        _configureFeedbackWidget();
    }

    private void _configureFeedbackWidget() {
        // It gets past this code, which contains stuff in the same 
        // "uservoicesdk" package as the problem class. 
        Config config = new Config("myapp.uservoice.com");
        UserVoice.init(config, this);
    }

    public void showFeedbackWindow(View v) {
        // Triggered by a button on the page
        UserVoice.launchUserVoice(this);  // Error is triggered by this line
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I cracked open the .apk (using [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)) that was installed and manually verified that the PortalActivity class, that it's complaining about, IS there:

[image: apk contents]

What could cause Android to not find the class?

***EDIT:***
I've changed around my project dependences & Java Build Path settings, and this is what I have now:

[image: Build Path - Projects]
[image: Build Path - Libraries]!
[image: Build Path - Order and Export]

I cleaned/re-built - no errors, and now I'm seeing the following:

1. MyApp.apk no longer has the com.uservoice.uservoicesdk package in it.  That package is now in  PortalActivity.apk, which I can see, from the console, is installed separately from my .apk.
   Console output:

> Uploading MyApp.apk onto device 'LG-MS770-275bcf0'
>   Installing MyApp.apk... 
>   Success! 
>   Project dependency found, installing: PortalActivity 
>   Uploading PortalActivity.apk onto device 'LG-MS770-275bcf0' 
>   Installing PortalActivity.apk... 
>   Success! 
>   Starting activity com.mycompany.myapp.MyActivity on device LG-MS770-275bcf0

2. Now my app dies during the `_configureFeedbackWidget()` method, above, with the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.service.uservoicesdk.Config`.

**So, what is the correct way to reference the `PortalActivity` project from my project such that my project can find PortalActivity's classes *at runtime*, and not just at build time?**

Comment: Post the code that gives this error

Comment: Im not familiar with Android dev or the apk files, but if they are anything like a traditional JAR file, simply having the dependency in there isnt enough, it must also be specified in the classpath in the jars manifest. I would expect an APK to have something similar.

Comment: This is usually caused by a linker error when building.  Usually because a library wasn't added properly. Sometimes simply rebuilding fixes it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android

Comment: @DeeV I've tried cleaning/re-building and closing/re-opening Eclipse, I've also made sure that the relevant jar is checked off in the "Order and Export" tab (as suggested by your link), with no luck...

Comment: did you added the activity in the manifest?

Comment: The "MyClass" Activity is in the manifest (assuming you mean AndroidManifest.xml).  Does the uservoice lib need to be specified in the manifest somehow also?

Comment: I just tried adding `<activity android:name="com.uservoice.uservoicesdk.activity.PortalActivity" />` to AndroidManifest.xml, but it still dies with the same error.