# Android multiple dex files defined

Tags: android, jar, dex

I was wondering is there a way of avoid multiple dex error ? I am using a library, I need some of its old classes from an older version and some of its new from a newer version. So when I add both jars then I get a multiple dex error. I know the cause of error, that is the both jars has same package name and same classes name.

Is there a way of avoiding this error? Is not could you please suggest an alternative. That'll be really helpful. But I've to use both jars.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project->properties->Java build path ->order and export.Then `Uncheck` android.support jar.

Then clean your project and run

Comment: No I am not talking about android support libraries. I am any library, Lets say I am using Lucene 3.6 and there are some classes in Lucene 3.7 that I want to use. But because of package and class name conflict I got duplicate dex error. How To handle this problem?

Comment: @BilalIslam delete one of them and run the project

Comment: Thats the problem. I need both :)

Comment: @BilalIslam then try like check one of them and uncheck another one.

Comment: @BilalIslam Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android)